# Is recursive bucketsort is better option

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

we know that in bucket sort we insert arr[i] element into bucket[n*array[i]] and use any sorting algorithm in each bucket and then recollect each bucket serially to get sorted list.
if we use any sorting algorithm then in worst-case senerio the sorting complexity will equal to the sub-sorting algorithm.
So I thought how it would be to use the same bucket sort recusively
here is the code for it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<float> bucketSort(vector<float> vect,int constant=1){
    if(vect.empty())return vect;
    if(vect.size()==1)return vect;
    bool same=true;
    for(int i=0;i<vect.size()-1;i++)
        if(vect[i]!=vect[i+1]){
            same=false;
            break;
        }
    if(same)return vect;
    vector<vector<float>> buckets(10);
    int size=vect.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        buckets[((int)(vect[i]*constant))%10].push_back(vect[i]);
    constant*=10;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        buckets[i]=bucketSort(buckets[i],constant);
    vector<float> result;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        int size=buckets[i].size();
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            result.push_back(buckets[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int size;
    cin>>size;
    vector<float> vect(size);
    float temp;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cin>>vect[i];
    vect=bucketSort(vect);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<vect[i]<<" ";
}
```

Can you please tell me is it a better option or not and what would be its time and space complexity.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that quicksort (with some bells and whistles to obviate pathological cases) is the best algorithm. And, with respect, the best implementation will be in your C++ Standard Library, not the one you build!

Comment: that is ok to use bucket sort recursively, its running time depends on number of buckets and input ditribution.

Comment: `((int)(vect[i]*constant))%10` Interesting... Assuming constant is 1, 11.0 will go into bucket 1 and 7.0 into 7, whereas 18.0 again goes into bucket 8. Sort order: 11.0, 7.0 18.0.

Comment: I am not sure, if we can neglect (re-)allocations as std::vector does in complexity calculations.

Comment: @Aconcagua pointed right, bucket sort is supposed to sort elements in range [0,1), you know your range and you need to specify `constant` accordingly, but this division modulo 10 is strange, you should multiply by 10 (number of buckets).

Comment: @Aconcagua please tell me the time complexity for this problem .

Comment: If your elements are evenly distributed and your number of buckets matches the size of the array, bucket sort will have O(n) average performance, otherwise the recursive sort's complexity will dominate. The latter condition is only true if `vect.size() <= 10` and the former condition is very likely not to be true in recursive calls to bucket sort, where your elements are going to be more similar in every recursive call due to you calling it on buckets of elements with the same hash. This looks to me like an O(n^2) implementation.

Comment: @Yola Range [0;1) was nowhere written... If buckets are defined in terms of equal ranges between min and max value, such limitation is not required any more either. With given limitation, the modulo should be fine (although constant == 1 is pointless then...), as the value/10 part was sorted in a previous iteration, i. e. is equal for all elements in the same bucket.

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, i know bucket sort from CLRS, there it was defined on [0,1), if particular data comes from range [a,b), then one need to map [a,b) to [0,1) with linear function *f*, and then bucket # could be found as f(A[i])*bucketsCount.

Comment: @Yola, `A(i) = (i - min)/(max - min)`... Pretty easy for real numbers, but rounding issues might throw in some trouble, but that's not my point, actually not either that I originally considered a more general definition of BS, only that `%` is OK *with* given limitation...

Comment: Of theoretical nature only, but with *real* numbers, the recursive BS *cannot* get better than O(n^2) as it would always be possible to find sets of numbers such that, no matter now many buckets we use, only one single value goes into one bucket and all the others into another, but as well single bucket, e. g. 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, ... for 10 buckets... Resembles selection sort then. With float, though, we only have a limited number of representable values, so if set of values get sufficiently large, this won't apply any more at some specific point...

Comment: The problem with recursive (top down) bucket sort is space complexity and concatenating buckets. For example, the entry level involves 10 buckets, the next level 100 buckets, the next level 1000 buckets. A least significant "digit" counting / radix sort avoids this issue and only requires one temporary array with the same size as the original array to do the sort. The buckets are variable in size (boundaries are determined by counting "instances" of digits), and end up "concatenated" at the end of each radix sort pass.